# With multiple dacpac, ignore 1 dacpac during deployment

Tags: publish, azure-pipelines, dacpac

I have a db project in my solution and I create a dacpac for that. I use that dacpac for my VSTS deployment. All is good till then.
Now I have to reference another dacpac in my project and make use of it.
I add that dacpac to my solution and use it. My DB project works fine. It builds fine too on VSTS
But the publish Dacpac fails with error stating that the referenced dacpac could not be found. I want to ignore that dacpac from being compared or making any changes to db since it's just a referenced Dacpac.
Let me know

Comment: How do you reference another dacpac to your project? Provide the detail steps here. On the other hand, can you deploy it manually without referenced dacpac file?

Comment: Is the referenced dacpac for the same database you are trying to deploy to or just used for cross-db/linked server database references?

Comment: Yes the referenced dacpac is for the same database but with different schema... Though I was able to include both the dacpac in my artifacts by specifying the proper path in Azure build definition. And in the publish step I just referenced the required dacpac. So it definitely checks the schema of another dacpac that was referenced but don't modify any tables for that dacpac. It only alters database for the required dacpac. This solution works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference the other dacpac but not deploy it you can specify the following on deployment to ignore it (using SqlPackage.exe or the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll library)

```
/p: IncludeCompositeObjects=false
```